# Error when using render function of react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I copy the code from https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html to my javascript file I get this error in browser console.

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

```
function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not wrap element inside the function.

Here is the small demo for you!
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-platform-1w13u

**Method 1:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const element = (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
  </div>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement);
```

OR

**Method 2:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );

  return element;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Tick />, rootElement);
```

You can go with any one approach.

Hope this will helpful for you!

Answer (score 1):

`element` has to be a react component:

```
function tick() {
  const Element = () => ( // Make it a functional component 
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(<Element/>, document.getElementById('root')); // Render as component
}
```

Also make sure you have the appropriate [transform plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) setup.